# Can flash read client side hardware information?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Can flash read client side hardware information such as RAM, CPU, Computer unique id hard drive size?

I know it can read the camera and maybe the monitor size but the above is still remain unknown to me.

Answer (score 2):

Short and long: No, that's not possible. All you can get is the version and the OS type.

Answer (score 0):

You could guestimate the cpu speed by running some basic calculations and seeing how long it took. If you have benchmarks with different speed computers, you could place them based on that. That'll depend on how much stuff they have running etc though. There's no way to get the actual sys info.

Comment: Like Linux BogoMIPS this would be entirely variable and pretty much useless, based on operating system (and version), Flash version, memory, CPU speed, CPU type (fast with floating point? SSE accelerated? Cache? Memory speed? Bus width?), system load, network speed, and possibly more. Too many factors.

Comment: @Thomas O - it could be useful if you created a game that has high and low graphic settings. You could possibly poll the speed to see if it is above a threshold to see what graphic settings it would default to.

Comment: I would prefer the game simply asking me what kind of graphics I want instead of running some complicated benchmark first.. :P

Answer (score 0):

That is not the answer of your exact question you have asked. However you can assign a random variable to a shared object in the first loading of your swf. This variable can identify the machine uniquely. After the following connections you can send this variable to the server. That way is the closest way of identifying different machines that the connections are coming.

Another way of doing this is can be using javascript first http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/How-to-Use-JavaScript-for-Hardware-Knowledge/ and communicate with your javascript through external interface http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html. 
Regards